# SQL Query Summary Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

A customer can have multiple Agreements, and each Agreement has multiple products (i.e. A - H in the image below).  I wrote the following query that give me the product count for each Agreement.  I then use RowNum to determine the Agreement and AgreementEndDate closest to today.

However, what I need to return is RowNum = 1 is: a) AgreementEndDate closest to today (and associated AgreementID and AgreementEffectiveDate) and a summary of products purchase.

So, RowNum 1 =

- AgreementID = 73838545
- AgreementEffectiveDate = 2015-05-28
- AgreementEndDate = 2018-05-31
- A = 1
- B = 1
- C = 1
- D = 1
- E = 1
- F = 1
- G = 1
- H = 0

[image]

```
Select 
    LA.*
from
    (select 
        CustomerID
        ,AgreementID
        ,min(CONVERT(char(10), AgreementEffectiveDate,126)) as 'AgreementEffectiveDate'
        ,min(CONVERT(char(10), AgreementEndDate,126)) as 'AgreementEndDate'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([A Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'A Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([B Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'B Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([C Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'C Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([D Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'D Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([E Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'E Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([F Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'F Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([G Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'G Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([H Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'H Agreement'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TPID ORDER BY AgreementEndDate ASC) AS RowNum
        from LicenseAgreement
        Group by CustomerID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate
        ) LA
    where TPID = '1789' --and RowNum = 1
order by RowNum, CustomerID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate
```

Comment: `and a summary of products purchase` - great: what's your product table?  What have you been trying so far, and what's blocking you?  Also, there isn't really any such thing as an "agreement end date" - there's "date where the agreement is no longer in effect", which is subtly different (exclusive upper bound instead of inclusive upper bound)

Comment: There is no one product table.  I actually have to inner join 8 other tables. 

Instead of LA.*, I have tried:
  LA.CustomerID
 ,sum([A Agreement})
 ,sum([B Agreement})
 ,sum([C Agreement})
 ,sum([D Agreement})
 ... and so forth. 

But I'm getting the same results. And yes, you are correct, there really is no end date, but agreement is no longer in effect.

Comment: ...can we get starting sample data and the result data you want to see?  If you're saying that this table already has summary data, and you don't need to access the other tables, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring the solution.  I just added an inner join.  Once I did this, everything worked.

This isn't the best way but it works.

```
Select 
    B.ID 
    ,B.AgreementID 
    ,B.AgreementEffectiveDate 
    ,B.AgreementEndDate
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[A Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'A Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[B Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'BAgreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[C Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'C Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[D Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'D Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[E Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'E Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[F Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'F Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[G Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'G Agreement'
    ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast(LA.[H Agreement] as float)) >= 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'H Agreement'
from
    (select 
        TPID 
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([A Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'A Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([B Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'B Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([C Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'C Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([D Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'D Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([E Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'E Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([F Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'F Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([G Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'G Agreement'
        ,(CASE WHEN sum(cast([H Agreement] as float)) >= 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'H Agreement'
        from LicenseAgreement
        Group by ID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate, AgreementEffectiveDate
        ) LA
    inner join (select 
        TPID 
        ,AgreementID
        ,min(CONVERT(char(10), AgreementEffectiveDate,126)) as 'AgreementEffectiveDate'
        ,min(CONVERT(char(10), AgreementEndDate,126)) as 'AgreementEndDate'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AgreementEndDate ASC) AS RowNum
        from LicenseAgreement
        Group by ID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate, AgreementEffectiveDate
    ) B ON b.TPID = LA.TPID 
    where RowNum = 1 
group by B.TPID,b.RowNum,b.AgreementID,b.AgreementEffectiveDate,b.AgreementEndDate
order by ID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate, RowNum
```